# What is the notation for the set of all $m\times n$ matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

Given that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the notation used for $n$-dimensional vectors, is there an accepted equivalent notation for matrices?

Comment: I wonder why no one proposed $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$ - is that incorrect?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^n$ is incorrect. Indeed it has dimension $m+n$ instead of $mn$. If you meant the tensor product instead, it has a correct dimension (but still there would be inconsistencies with coordinate changes in that case).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, then $$A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$$

Comment: Since $\times$ is the official symbol for multiplying integers, this notation is in principle ambiguous: $2\times3=6$ would seem to imply $\Bbb R^{2\times 3}=\Bbb R^6$, but the latter is not a space of matrices. I agree that this is nitpicking, and would apply to the term "$m\times n$ matrix" itself too, but I personally prefer notations which use a comma rather than $\times$ (or nothing) between $m$ and $n$ (and this applies to matrix subscripts as well).

Comment: I agree. If you just wrote $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ it wouldn't be necessarily clear $A$ is a matrix.

Answer (score 15):

As you can see from the previous two answers, several notations are in common usage, so it's best to say what you mean the first time you use it to be completely clear. (For what it's worth, I often use $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, which is different again).

Comment: Does your notation refer to $m \times n$ or to $n \times m$ matrices? (The OP asks for $m \times n$.)

Comment: @Ryan Thanks - force of habit.

Comment: Np, I asked because my textbook just did the same thing, and it got me confused (thus ending up here after searching for the answer).

Answer (score 8):

The vector space of real matrices with $n$ rows and $m$ columns is denoted by $\mathcal{M}_{n,m}(\mathbb R)$ and its $nm$-dimensional vector space so it's isomorphic to $\mathbb R^{nm}$

Comment: Oh, I did not pay attention to what the OP wrote and yet I think my answer does not make confusion.

Answer (score 4):

The notation $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is in fact correct. We should be careful with the symbol '$\times$' that in this case does not means an integer product but a group product that, as a result, is a new group in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with elements of the form $(m, n)$, and thus the matrix $A$ is contained in it.

Answer (score 1):

I like the notation $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ for the set of $m\times n$ matrices because it is consistent with the notations below, which are common, if not standard:

- $Y^X$ is the set of all functions $X \to Y$
- $n$ denotes the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$
- $m \times n$ is the cartesian product $\{1,2,\dots,m\} \times \{1,2,\dots,n\}$
- An $m \times n$ matrix over a set $Y$ is a function $m \times n \to Y$

Answer (score 0):

I usually go with $\text{M}_n^m(\mathbb{R})$ or $\mathfrak{M}_n^m(\mathbb{R})$, where the superscript is the number of rows and the subscript is the number of columns. This avoids the confusion of thinking that the matrix space is the same as $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$ which is the main motivation for notations such as $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}=(\mathbb{R}^m)^n=\mathbb{R}^m\times\dots\times\mathbb{R}^m$. Although these spaces are isomorphic but they have their own identity like similar twins!

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question, but I didn't see this proposed:

You can write $\texttt{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$

The set of homomorphisms (linear maps) between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: It's not usual to use this to denote the set of matrice. $\texttt{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ and the set of matrice are identified only after you choose a basis.